# Performing antidifferentiation using $d/dr$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

So I'm confused about how to approach this question:
$$\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac12v^2\right)=-\frac{GM}{r^2}.$$ The solution seems fairly straightforward:
$$\frac{1}{2} v^{2}=-\int \frac{G M}{r^{2}} d r=\frac{G M}{r}+C$$ but I don't really understand what specifically is happening.

For context, I'm a university student studying maths, but I feel like I never really "got" the notation for derivatives. It seems weird that the $d/dr$ is being treated as a variable and being shifted to the RHS, and then where does the $d$ (from $dr/d$) go?

And why is the LHS constant? We are integrating with respect to $r$ and thus we can consider the LHS as some constant. Say we were integrating the constant k with respect to x, then the result is $kx + c$, so why isn't the result not $(1/2)\times (v^2)\times r$ on the LHS?

Help is very much appreciated.

For reference, here is the full [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjQnw.png).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just taking anti-derivatives with respect to $r$ on both sides. Since anti-derivatives are only determined up to an additive constant, you get an additional ${}+C$ on one of the sides of the equation.

Basically, your situation is the following: you are given
$$
f'(r) = g(r)
$$
and an anti-derivative $G$ of $g$. Since $f$ is an anti-derivative of $f'$ and $G$ is an anti-derivative of $g$, you conclude that
$$
f(r) = G(r) + C.
$$

Here $f(r) = \frac{1}{2} v(r)^2$ and $g(r) = -\frac{GM}{r^2}$.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now! 

With regards to the second part of the question, the solution is approached in a way that is foreign to me. https://imgur.com/a/xqetFdp

How come the series converges, ie. |s/R| is < 1. If s is the height ABOVE the surface and R is the radius to the surface, shouldn't s > R? Also, how come we "retain" only the leading term. What allows us to discard the rest of the series?

Thanks!

Comment: @Sov Please ask a separate question for that matter and write out the problem instead of linking to a picture of text.

Answer (score 2):

The mathematical detail you're missing is that derivatives & differential operators aren't true fractions. The *physical* detail you're missing is $v=dr/dt=\sqrt{2(GM/r+C)}$. I'll leave you to solve this, to get $t$ as a function of $r$, with the substitution $r=\tfrac{GM}{C}\tan^2u$.(Doing so isn't necessary for the linked original question, but it'll improve your intuitions.)